# Is an electron always in an eigenstate of *some* spin observable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, superposition, observables

Is it right to think that an isolated electron is always in an eigenstate of the spin observable along $some$ axis? For instance, even if the electron is not in an eigenstate of $S_x, S_y,$ and $S_z$, there would be some axis $i$ so that the electron is in an eigenstate of $i$-spin. Is that right?

Comment: An electron is not a thing/system that has a state on its own. If we make a spin measurement on one electron, then we get a measurement outcome that is either up or down.  If we rotate the measurement axis by 90 degrees and we repeat, then we get another random up or down. We can repeat this as many times as we like and the outcome will be a random sequence of ups and downs. To say that "the electron was in such and such a state" is not a useful interpretation of quantum mechanics. What causes the measurement outcome is not just "the electron", but also the choice of the measurement system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every spin state in the space of spin states - the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) - is an eigenstate of the angular momentum operator associated with the axis that passes through state when it is represented as a point on the Bloch sphere.

Comment: this is true if the state is pure but a single isolated electron could still be in a mixed state, in which case it would not necessarily be in an eigenstate of a spin observable.